# HTML email: 3 column images on mobile - Rounding down issue

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm having an issue with my 3 column images when it rounds down the pixels on mobile.

On desktop the images of course just show each as 200px wide, and on mobile I've set them to 33% (I made it 33.334% to avoid having a big gap to the right of the images)

However, I still have one single pixel of gap on the right, that I can't get away on mobile. [Here's the pixel I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnDdg.png)

Anyone who can help?

```css
<style type="text/css">a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: #666666;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  width: auto !important;
  background: #ffffff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  *,
  *::before,
  *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body {
    width: auto !important;
  }
  .rsd33,
  td.rsd33 img {
    width: 33.334%!important;
    height: auto!important;
  }
  .rsd,
  td.rsd img {
    width: 100%!important;
    height: auto!important;
  }
}

</style>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
  <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rsd">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="rsd">
          <!--[if gte mso 9]>
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr valign="top">
     <td>
     <![endif]-->
          <table width="200" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="rsd33">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="rsd"><img src="http://image.e.bianco.com/lib/fe8a13727261017972/m/1/200x100.gif" width="200" height="" align="center" border="0" link="" /></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <!--[if gte mso 9]>
     </td>
     <td>
     <![endif]-->
          <table width="200" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="rsd33">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="rsd"><img src="http://image.e.bianco.com/lib/fe8a13727261017972/m/1/200x100.gif" width="200" height="" align="center" border="0" link="" /></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <!--[if gte mso 9]>
     </td>
     <td>
     <![endif]-->
          <table width="200" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="rsd33">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="rsd"><img src="http://image.e.bianco.com/lib/fe8a13727261017972/m/1/200x100.gif" width="200" height="" align="center" border="0" link="" /></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <!--[if gte mso 9]>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <![endif]-->
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try full hybrid method with divs. I have re-coded bits of your email to add in what I think will work best. If you have any issues let me know.

I have also removed your classes so in iOS the code below will not be dependent on media queries.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />


<style type="text/css">a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: #666666;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  width: auto !important;
  background: #ffffff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  *,
  *::before,
  *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body {
    width: auto !important;
  }
  .rsd33,
  td.rsd33 img {
    width: 33.334%!important;
    height: auto!important;
  }
  .rsd,
  td.rsd img {
    width: 100%!important;
    height: auto!important;
  }
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
  <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rsd">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="rsd" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; font-size: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 600px;">
          <!--[if gte mso 9]>
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr valign="top">
     <td width="200">
   <![endif]-->
         <div style="max-width: 200px;display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><img src="http://image.e.bianco.com/lib/fe8a13727261017972/m/1/200x100.gif" height="" align="center" border="0" link="" style="width:100%;max-width:200px; height:auto;" /></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
   </div>
          <!--[if gte mso 9]>
     </td>
     <td width="200">
     <![endif]-->
         <div style="max-width: 200px;display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class=""><img src="http://image.e.bianco.com/lib/fe8a13727261017972/m/1/200x100.gif" height="" align="center" border="0" link="" style="width:100%;max-width:200px; height:auto;" /></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
   </div>
          <!--[if gte mso 9]>
     </td>
     <td width="200">
     <![endif]-->
         <div style="max-width: 200px;display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class=""><img src="http://image.e.bianco.com/lib/fe8a13727261017972/m/1/200x100.gif" height="" align="center" border="0" link="" style="width:100%;max-width:200px; height:auto;" /></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
   </div>
          <!--[if gte mso 9]>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <![endif]-->
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your solution.
I'm just not sure I really like the fluid hybrid method. I've looked at it a lot, but I feel like there are limitations.
I don't see, how I easily can hide objects on mobile devices or change the font size or padding on mobile, but not on desktop. etc.?

And furthermore, I also like to use images with coded space in between (for instance 3 images with 10 px between eachother, also on mobile)
Is that possible with the fluid hybrid method with percentages?

Comment: Since Gmail now supports media queries anything is possible. If coded right your design should be able to do it. There is a trick I use when coding hybrid method. Borrow spaces from the left and right margin. Example if side margins are 30px your outer margins will use 10px block and the inner block will use 20px margin. This way when the code going responsive you have 20px margin on mobiles and your 10px blocks stack. Hope that made sense.

Comment: I don't use percentages, I use width 100% with Max width. The outer tables are controlled by outlook conditional statements, classes and max width tables.

Comment: Okay, so I still have to use media queries for some things.
I'm just not really sold to the hybrid method.
I also just tested the method you described, and it still has the issue as mentioned in the original post about a white line to the right of the images on some iOS versions.

Comment: Its up to you. I have been using hybrid since it started and have been using it still. If i need more cosmetic changes then i rely on media queries. Since Gmail went responsive there is 95% of devices that can read media queries. So you can choose which method works. Hybrid doesnt mean you dont use media queries, it just means you dont have to rely fully on them for a few things

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation and your help :-)

Comment: No problems. If you want to find me just search for syfer_darknight and message me.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I could see was a gap below the upper graphics and along the right side of the third graphic using iPhone 5.

The best fix for this issue is to add an `outline` to the class. something like this:

```
td.rsd33 img {
  width: 33.334%!important;
  height: auto!important;
  outline: 2px solid #0000ff;
}
```

If you apply that to your media query, it will fix the issue with iPhone 5 and not affect the graphics in larger size email clients.

Good luck.